# Point values show up in Google Fit API Explorer, but not in PHP app

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-fit

I am using the following PHP command to retrieve steps from Google Fit:

```
$dataset->get('me','derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:derive_step_deltas<-derived:com.google.step_count.cumulative:com.google.android.gms:HTC:HTC One:3863da10:soft_step_counter','1397515179728708316-1423267952728708316');
```

This receives a Google_Service_Fitness_Dataset, however no points are included:

```
{
 "minStartTimeNs": "1397515179728708316",
 "maxEndTimeNs": "1423267952728708316",
 "dataSourceId":     "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:derive_step_deltas\u003c-derived:com.google.step_count.cumulative:com.google.android.gms:HTC:HTC One:3863da10:soft_step_counter"
}
```

When I use the API Explorer, it shows the above dataset in addition to several hundred points in the results.  Example:

```
"point": [
  {
   "startTimeNanos": "1416618389952000000",
   "endTimeNanos": "1416618449952000000",
   "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
   "originDataSourceId":     "derived:com.google.step_count.cumulative:com.google.android.gms:HTC:HTC One:3863da10:soft_step_counter",
   "value": [
    {
     "intVal": 1
    }
   ],
   "modifiedTimeMillis": "1416620672890"
  }
```

Is there something I am doing wrong that is causing these points to show up in the API Explorer but not in my PHP app?

I have also tried using the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), however it also does not show the points.  I am currently only using the fitness activity read scope in all implementations (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read).  Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: Its possible that the end time you are requesting in your php script is too far in to the future, causing a bug in google fit?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just tried with a more current ending timestamp (1423267952728708316) and still encountering the same error.  Definitely was worth a try!

Comment: It looks like the PHP client is converting the `<-` characters in your request to `\u003c-` in your response. Could that be the reason? Try using the same `dataSourceId` you used in the API explorer in your php client.